# Filter 0 values and output chi square results to a data frame in R

Tags: r, filtering, chi-squared

I have data that consists of many Cases (over 600) where I have two independent assessments to compare.  I want to determine, based on the relative abundance of species observed, whether the differences between the assessments are due to random variation (differing plot locations/methodologies) or due to human error. The assessments were conducted by a forest manager (FM; generally an ocular estimate) and the ministry responsible for validating the result (MNRF; intensive plot based survey). A result with a p-value <0.05 would indicate that it is either highly unlikely that the two samples were taken from the same population, or that the less intensive method is not sufficiently accurate.

Species composition has been converted to counts of trees by species based on the number of plots established by MNRF.  There are several species that may be encountered, but in each case, there are generally less than 6.  Species are identified by a two letter code (e.g. PJ = jack pine, BW = white birch).  An example of a single case is:

```
> head(case545)

  Case Source  PJ SB BW PO BF SW PR LA MR CW PW
1  545   MNRF  68 21 17 15  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  545     FM 101 13 13  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I can calculate the statistic I want for this case using the code:

```
chisq.test(rbind(c(68,21,17,15,1),c(101,13,13,0,0)))
```

My problem is I have many many cases and I can't figure out how to tell R which values to use in each case.  As far as I can tell the logic flow should be

1. identify and eliminate species where both assessments recorded a value of 0
2. ensure that the values are organized correctly for chisq.test
3. run the test and output a new table with the X2 and p value for each case

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of use but might requiere some changes based on some nuances you might have with your data.

For this example I recreate two cases with the naming convention `caseXXX`

```
case545 <- data.frame(Case="545", 
Source=c("XX","X1"), PJ=c(68,21),SB=c(17,13),BW=c(1,0), SW=c(0,0))
case546 <- data.frame(Case="546",   
Source=c("XX","X1"), PJ=c(100,300),SB=c(0,0),BW=c(400,0), SW=c(300,500))
```

We then create a list of all the data.frames with that naming convention

```
library(dplyr)
DF <- ls(pattern = "case")
```

We then apply a function to the list of of data.frames and bind the rows together to make one single data.frame.

This function does what you are asking. 
1-Get rid of columns with only 0s
2-Compute the statistical test
3-Give us the X2 statistic and the p-value as a data.frame

```
Output <- bind_rows(lapply(DF, function(DF){
  TMP <- get(DF)
  TMP <- TMP %>% 
    select(grep(pattern = F,colSums( TMP != 0) == 0))
  TMP <- chisq.test(rbind(TMP[1,-c(1:2)],TMP[2,-c(1:2)]))
  TMP <- data.frame(X2=TMP$statistic,p=TMP$p.value,case=DF)
  return(TMP)
}))

> Output
          X2             p    case
1   4.703423  9.520608e-02 case545
2 550.000000 3.706956e-120 case546
```

Comment: Thanks!  I also want the degrees of freedom in the output so I edited the last line to read: 
TMP <- data.frame(X2=TMP$statistic,d_f=TMP$parameter,p=TMP$p.value,case=DF)

Comment: My actual data set has 13 possible species (most are 0s).  I was able to generate 6 cases (2 obs of 13 variables) as you suggested. Unfortunately, the test run threw the following error

 Error in select(., grep(pattern = F, colSums(TMP != 0) == 0)) : 
  unused argument (grep(pattern = F, colSums(TMP != 0) == 0))

Comment: With this code there shouldn't be an issue for the numer of species (that's columns right?). Are there cases (or source-case combinations) where there are no observations for any column?

Comment: Columns are species. Values of 0 denote no observations of that species in the area assessed. I get the same error running the code exactly as you provided it (thanks so much) and I haven't been able to figure out how to resolve it.

Comment: So, after many attempts to resolve the errors I was getting above working in RStudio, I tried running it in R.  It works!  I was surprised that this was the case.  Has anyone else encountered errors in RStudio that do not get thrown in R?